# How do I count blanks in multiple columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've been trying to get a percentage on the amount of blanks cells I have within a table to make a chart that shows the data completeness of said table. The issue I'm having now is that I'm new to Power BI and lack the needed knowledge to handle this.

One method I've found is creating 2 measures for each column, 1 using COUNTBLANK to count the blanks and one COUNTA to count the non-blanks. The issue with this method is that I would have to create about 28 measures for each table to get the results. This wouldn't be ideal for my query speed.

Is there a better solution for said problem, perhaps using PQ or a calculated table?